# fabricjs does not render properly when simulating a mobile touch device

Tags: fabricjs

I am using threejs to manage a canvas (canvas0) (for example, to zoom-in/out and pan) and fabricjs for annotation (canvas1).
This works fine in the Chrome browser, when using mouse events, but does not work properly when simulating mobile touch device, through the "Toggle Device Toolbar" button in the chrome debugger.
An example that demonstrates it is in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/Lk2hmq1o/73/show)

Specifically, when drawing on canvas0, the real-time created path is renderred in the wrong place (although when ending the touch the path appears in the correct location).
I observe that fabricjs lowerCanvas has the correct size (of 256*256 px) as defined in the code, but the upperCanvas shows a wrong size of 512*512 px which is nowhere specified in the code.
(the upperCanvas is needed to render the path during creation and before it is finalized).
Occassionaly upperCanvas, after refreshing the page has the correct size, similar to lowerCanvas, and then the path is renderred correctly.
But other times, a wrong size of 512*512 px appears and then the problem appears.
Reloading the page with "hard reset" option does not solve the problem.

The problem can be demnostrated by:

- clicking F12 in Chrome (to get the debugger)
- clicking on the "Toggle device toolbar" button and selecting one of the simulated devices (e.g. iPhoneSE).
- Reloading the page in this configuration (by pressing F5)
- drawing on Canvas0

See the code in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/Lk2hmq1o/73/) and to run in full view use [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/Lk2hmq1o/73/show)

```
let dummyCodeToSatisfyStackOverflow = 3;
```

What sets the upperCanvas to be 512*512 px?
How can I set the size of the upperCanvas? (calling fabricCanvas.setDimensions({width:256, height:256}) only sets the lowerCanvas);

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350747/fabric-js-patterns-how-create-pattern-for-canvas-background-from-rects-without) I set fabric.devicePixelRatio, e.g. `fabric.devicePixelRatio = 1;` , before initializing the canvas and this solved the problem.